How can I get the value from an API call result using C#?
I make an API call and the result is as follows.
This is the data:
[
    {{
         "Id": "7",
         "Type": "user",
         "Status": 1,
         "Name": "Bob",
     }},
     {{
         "Id": "8",
         "Type": "user",
         "Status": 1,
         "Name": "Mary",
     }}
]

I am trying to retrieve the values, for example let's say Name from each so I end up with MyName and MyName2:
   var a = JArray.Parse(data);
   List<string> resultList = new List<string>();

   foreach (var item in a)
   {
       string str = item["Name"].ToString() + ";"
   }

   return resultList;

But I get an exception saying that it can't access Name.
How can I do this?

Are you sure your JSON is valid? There are nested braces resulting in the JSON being invalid. Your JSON should be in this structure: [{...}, {...}]

First, it seems like your JSON object is not in the correct format. The correct JSON object should be sth like -
[
  {
    "Id": "7",
    "Type": "user",
    "Status": 1,
    "Name": "Bob"
  },
  {
    "Id": "8",
    "Type": "user",
    "Status": 1,
    "Name": "Mary"
  }
]

Second, you can define a class that can represent the JSON object. For example,
public class Customer
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Then, you can deserialize the object
List<Customer> customers = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Customer>>(jsonString); //jsonString you  get from API call
foreach (var customer in customers)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Name: {customer.Name});
}

